# Elasticsearch script:query (java.lang.String, java.lang.Long) values: [yyyy-MM-dd, 1591488000000]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the result when the end date of project is less then current date base on group.

> MApping:

```
{ "supply": {
"properties": {
  "rotation_list": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "project_end_date": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "end_date": {
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      },
      "total_days": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}}}
```

> data

```
{"rotation_list": [
{
  "project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"
    },
    {
      "end_date": "2020-07-07"
    }
  ],
  "total_days": 23
},
{
  "project_end_date": [
    {
      "end_date": "2020-08-07"
    }
  ],
  "total_days": 26
}]}
```

> query:

```
{"query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "rotation_list.project_end_date",
            "query": {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "lang": "groovy",
                  "inline": "def ratable =false;def now_date = new Date();for(i in doc['rotation_list.project_end_date.end_date'].values){def date_check = [];for (j in i){def long_to_str = new Date(j).format('yyyy-MM-dd');def compare_date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', long_to_str);if (compare_date < now_date) {date_check.add(true);} else {date_check.add(false);}};if (!date_check.contains(false)){ratable = true;break}else{ratable = false}};if(ratable){return true}else {return false}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}}}
```

> Error i am getting.

```
{"type": "missing_method_exception","reason": "No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.Long) values: [yyyy-MM-dd, 1591488000000] Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), parse(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.TimeZone), wait(), clone(), grep()"}
```

So basically i was trying to check the group end date of each project section less than the current date then only return.

Comment: You are trying to get the date from ES. It is stored as `long`. First you convert long to date then parse it in java.

Comment: How do i convert long to date Gibbs

Comment: Hi Gibbs, It's working thanks. But now the problem is i changes all the dates greater then the current date. After that also i am getting the result.

Comment: Can you add the updated query?

Comment: If i changed all the dates it's not returning any result. which is fine. if i keep like this: end dates of first two as "2020-07-01" and "2020-08-02". And the next project section end date is "2020-08-13". Then also it's returning the result.

Comment: @Gibbs I have updated the query and data as well. Same script is working fine in Groovy. Not sure why it's not working with elasticsearch.

Comment: I am not aware of groovy. But I doubt why do you use `rotation_list.project_end_date.end_date` instead `rotation_list.project_end_date`. You need to iterate this one. isnt?

Comment: Because it's a nested path data. And it will take the value this way.